# Unable to click a button in a table using webdriver

Tags: java, extjs, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I need to double click on a element(named users) which is inside a table. Tried with xpath but I get a error saying 'unable to locate element'. I also tried with className, linkText, tagName. Could anyone please with this.

Here is the piece of html code

```html
<div id="gridpanel-1064" class="x-panel filesystem-filegrid x-grid-with-row-lines x-border-item x-box-item x-panel-default x-grid" style="right: auto; left: 305px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 1373px; height: 343px;">
<div id="gridpanel-1064_header" class="x-panel-header x-docked x-panel-header-default x-docked-top x-panel-header-docked-top x-panel-header-default-docked-top x-layout-fit" style="width: 1373px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div id="toolbar-1075" class="x-toolbar x-docked x-toolbar-default x-docked-top x-toolbar-docked-top x-toolbar-default-docked-top x-box-layout-ct" style="width: 1373px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 32px;">
<div id="headercontainer-1065" class="x-grid-header-ct x-docked x-grid-header-ct-default x-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-default-docked-top x-box-layout-ct" style="border-width: 1px; width: 1373px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 59px;">
<div id="gridpanel-1064-body" class="x-panel-body x-grid-body x-panel-body-default x-layout-fit x-panel-body-default" style="width: 1373px; left: 0px; height: 226px; top: 84px;">
    <div id="gridview-1074" class="x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable" style="overflow: auto; margin: 0px; width: 1371px; height: 224px;" tabindex="-1">
        <table id="gridview-1074-table" class="x-gridview-1074-table x-grid-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" tabindex="-1" style="width: 918px;">
            <colgroup>
            <colgroup>
            <colgroup>
            <colgroup>
            <colgroup>
            <colgroup>
            <colgroup>
            <colgroup>
            <colgroup>
            <tbody id="gridview-1074-body">
                <tr id="gridview-1074-record-ext-record-23" class="x-grid-row x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="0" data-recordid="ext-record-23" data-boundview="gridview-1074">
                <tr id="gridview-1074-record-ext-record-24" class="x-grid-row x-grid-row-alt x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="1" data-recordid="ext-record-24" data-boundview="gridview-1074">
                <tr id="gridview-1074-record-ext-record-25" class="x-grid-row x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="2" data-recordid="ext-record-25" data-boundview="gridview-1074">
                <tr id="gridview-1074-record-ext-record-26" class="x-grid-row x-grid-row-alt x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="3" data-recordid="ext-record-26" data-boundview="gridview-1074">
                <tr id="gridview-1074-record-ext-record-27" class="x-grid-row x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="4" data-recordid="ext-record-27" data-boundview="gridview-1074">
                    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1100 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable x-grid-cell-special x-grid-cell-row-checker">
                    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1066 x-unselectable x-action-col-cell">
                    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1067 x-unselectable ">
                        <div class="x-grid-cell-inner" style="text-align:left;" unselectable="on">users</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1068 x-unselectable x-action-col-cell">
                    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1069 x-unselectable ">
                    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1070 x-unselectable ">
                    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1071 x-unselectable ">
                    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1072 x-unselectable ">
                    <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1073 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable ">
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well what XPath selector did you try? Is this in an IFrame?

Comment: 1. This was the statement what I tired using XPath                 WebElement selectbtn1Element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[5]/tr[3]/div"));  2. No there is no IFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your current XPath is wrong:

```
//table/tbody/tr[5]/tr[3]/div
```

Look at what it does.

It will go into the `table`, into that `table`'s `tbody`, into the **fifth** `tr` (row), then the mistake is, it will then go into **third** `tr` within that (row, remember?)

Take that and compare it to what you've got.

You want, probably:

```
//table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/div
```

As in, the **third** `td` (cell) within the **fifth** tr (row).

Comment: thanks for the correction :) I tried doing this however I'm getting a error saying that Exception occured :-( Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/div[text()='users']"}
Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds

Comment: Using your supplied HTML, it works for me. What changes in the HTML? As in, fire the test off once, then again, compare the HTML output. Since you are using positional indexers, if the position changes it is going to work. You could try an XPath that is less reliant on positions: `//table//descendant::div[text()='users']`. Inspect the page using Chrome Developer tools, post a screenshot of what you see.

Comment: I gave the full xpath from starting of the html page. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath will select the div containing the text **`users`** whose class is **`x-grid-cell-inner`**

---

**XPath**

```
//div[contains(., 'users') and contains(@class, 'x-grid-cell-inner')]
```

---

**Finds Element**

```
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner" style="text-align:left;" unselectable="on">users</div>
```

---

You'll need to apply additional qualifiers to the XPath if there are multiple divs with these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='gridview-1074-table']/tbody/tr[5]/tr[3]/div")).click();
```

Comment: the table id is getting changed every time. I tried with and without specifying the table id but it isn't working

Comment: Use regular expression using javascript in place of 1074. So that it will not fail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(string(), 'users')]"));
```

Comment: I'm getting a exception saying "Unable to locate element"